# 403 on S3 bucket object in browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've a private bucket with OAI and CloudFront. When I upload an item to the bucket I can visit it using the CloudFront URL but not via the S3 url:

My policy looks like this

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCloudFrontRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity xxx"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::xxx/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

My IAM user has the permission to upload and get from the bucket.
Now I want that my user (or my account) can visit the S3 URL (not the CloudFront URL) to access the object in the bucket without the need to make the bucket public.

How can I do this?

I tried to update the bucket policy like this but it didn't work.

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCloudFrontRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity xxx"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::xxx/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPolicyRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "xxxxx"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::xxx/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

From the CLI my user can get and upload objects.

Comment: Good answer by erhanux but you can use S3 presigned url created by any IAM user/role which has permission of S3 and give it to the user, using this, you don't need to make the object public. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IAM or bucket policies give you API level access to S3. It is not possible to download S3 files without making buckets public.